# How to discover relationships between features?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-engineering

I'm an undergraduate fairly new to statistics. I am trying to find relationships between the features of a dataset. The dataset in question consists of 5000 objects each with up to 23 features.

I was looking for methods which could relate many features. The idea would be to find a sort of "equation" that would relate some features.

My guess is that this problem would have something to do with regression analysis. In the past MIC was applied to this dataset, but without any results. From what I understand, it is limited to only analyzing the relationship between 2 features at a time.

I was suggested to use Neural Networks. However, in my limited understanding, I'm not sure the data would be big enough to do so. Furthermore, arent NN like black-boxes, would it be possible to extract how it does a prediction?

Any pointers of possibly useful techniques/resources to learn from, are greatly appreciated!
Many thanks for the help.

Comment: To clarify - are you looking to predict a variable given some other variables, or do you want to understand the relationship between variables?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to understant the relationship between variables.

Comment: You may want to give a little more information about what your data is and what you're trying to do. A great bulk of statistics is about understanding relationships between variables so it's tough to give any specific advice. Regression is a good place to start though - easy to use, easy to interpret and tends to be fairly robust in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDA  *(Exploratory data analysis)*

---

One of the basic techniques is using correlation and with that scatterplots, but like you mentioned that limits you to two features at a time.

As you have quite a number of features, I would suggest that you use something like a **biplot** instead. A biplot will plot all the features at the same time. I actually used it in an EDA for a data set last year. It had about 65000 observations and 65 features.

Depending on the nature of your data, you might also consider using **histograms** (mostly for categorical data).

I have also seen many people using **heat maps**. I like to use these to see where missing values are, but they can also be helpful to some degree in determining the relationship between features.

#### Model building

---

> I was suggested to use Neural Networks. However, in my limited understanding, I'm not sure the data would be big enough to do so. Furthermore, aren't NN like black-boxes, would it be possible to extract how it does a prediction?

When it comes to model building you can possibly look at **multiple regression**. Of course the great thing about multiple regression is that the model is still interpretable. When it comes to neural networks, these are very difficult to interpret. You can use back propagation, but in the workplace I cannot see how you will explain to a client how that works.

As for the size of your data set, a lecturer told me that in their opinion you need at least 10000 observations before you can start thinking about fitting a neural network (I don't have any other source that confirms this).

Some other models that I would consider,

1. **LASSO** and/or Ridge regression
2. **Random forest**

Comment: Thanks a lot, will look into biplots! Would definitly be interested in and would greatly appreciate any material.

Comment: That answer is written for the case where you have a dependent variable.  That doesn't seem to apply here.  I would use variable clustering as a start.  See examples [here](https://hbiostat.org/rms).